# sql server - how to set rows as columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

hopefully someone can help me with this. I have a table that looks like the following

```
ID  | Column | New Value | ModifiedDate

223 | Num    | 98        | 03/01/2018
223 | Country| IRE       | 03/01/2018
223 | User   | Bob       | 03/01/2018
222 | User   | Lily      | 01/01/2018
222 | Num    | 72        | 01/01/2018
222 | Country| UK        | 01/01/2018
222 | User   | Wendy     | 02/01/2018
222 | Num    | 22        | 02/01/2018
222 | Country| UK        | 02/01/2018
```

I want a query that somehow merges all this into rows based on ID and modified date. So for the above table, I want the following output

```
ID  | Num | Country | User | Modified Date
222 |  72 |   UK    | Lily | 01/01/2018
222 |  22 |   UK    |Wendy | 02/01/2018
223 |  98 |  IRE    | Bob  | 03/01/2018
```

Can someone help with this? I have looked for similar problems on here but can't find anything that actually works when I use it against my table?

Also, the number of IDs can change so it would have to be dynamic?

Many thanks for any help!!

Comment: have a look at `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: Why are there *two* rows for ID? Converting rows to columns is one thing. Using one of the pivoted values as a key is another. Why is `72` returned for Lily instead of 22 ? You'll have to explain the logic for grouping the rows

Comment: because the date this column was changed is different. 72 on 01/01/2018 and 22 on 02/01/2018

Comment: _can't find anything that actually works_.. I suggest you find something that almost works and explain what you did and what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName
   PIVOT ( MAX(NewValue)
           FOR [Column]
           IN ([Num] , [Country] , [User])
         )p
```

Answer (score 0):

Old-School pivoting works also

```
select 
ID, 
max(case when [Column] = 'Num' then [New Value] end) as Num,
max(case when [Column] = 'Country' then [New Value] end) as Country,
max(case when [Column] = 'User' then [New Value] end) as [User],
ModifiedDate
from YourTable 
group by ID, ModifiedDate
order by ID, ModifiedDate;
```